# jQuery Mobile form submission results in "undefined" submission page

Tags: html, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I have a form that I am looking to submit using jQuery Mobile. However, when you submit the form, the page changes to the submission page and displays "undefined." Nothing else is on the page.

Here is the jquery/ajax:

```
$("#submit_comment").click(function() {

            var formData = $("#comment_form").serialize();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "forms/comment_form.php",
                cache: false,
                data: formData,
                success: onSuccess,
                error: onError          

            });

            return false;

        });
```

here is the HTML-form:

```
<form id="comment_form" action="forms/comment_form.php" method="POST" style="display:none";>
                    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $session_user_id; ?>">
                    <textarea id="text_area_input" name="comment" placeholder="Enter a comment here."></textarea>
                    <input type="submit" id="submit_comment" name="submit_comment" value="Post Comment">

                </form>
```

Here is the submission page:

```
if (empty($_POST['submit_comment']) === false) {
    if (empty($_POST['user_id']) === true) {
        $comment_errors[] = 'Sorry, there was an error submitting your comment. Please try again.';
    }
    if (empty($_POST['comment']) === true) {
        $comment_errors[] = 'You must enter something into the comment field.'; 
    } 
    if (empty($comment_errors) === false) { 
        echo "<div id='comment_errors'><?php echo output_comment_errors($comment_errors);?></div>";
    } else if (empty($comment_errors) === true) {
        $comment = $_POST['comment'];
        $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];       
        echo "ok";
    }
}
```

Comment: You should remove forms action="forms/comment_form.php" attribute. You are using ajax, you don't need to submit it in an old fashion way. You have a return false inside a click event, it will only work if you use it inside a submit event.

Comment: When I do that the page will not change to the submission page. Could you be more specific about where the return false should be placed?

Comment: I fix your code and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/B8mrX/

HTML :

```
<form id="comment_form">
        <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value=""/>
        <textarea id="text_area_input" name="comment" placeholder="Enter a comment here."></textarea>
        <input type="submit" id="submit_comment" name="submit_comment" value="Post Comment"/>
 </form>
```

JS:

```
$('#comment_form').on('submit', function(e){       
    e.preventDefault();

    var formData = $("#comment_form").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "forms/comment_form.php",
        cache: false,
        data: formData,
        success: function (result) {
            alert('Success');
        },
        error: function (request,error) {
            alert('Network error has occurred please try again!');
        }        

    });    

    return false;
});
```

As you can see I have removed form attributes method and action.

Instead of button click event I am using form submit event. Submit event is prevented with a **e.preventDefault();** and **return false** and rest is on ajax. I have added success and error callback function inside a ajax call but you can do it as you wish.

**EDIT :**

This is a working example, just put it inside an new HTMl and test it. I have forgoten 2 things inside a jsFiddle example. First submit event need to be inside a correct jQuery Mobile page event (without it submit event will not be bound to the form) and we need to turn off classic jQuery Mobile form submit by adding data-ajax="false" attribute to form tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://www.dragan-gaic.info/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>      
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>    
    <script>
        $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){      
            $('#comment_form').on('submit', function(e){

                e.preventDefault();

                var formData = $("#comment_form").serialize();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "forms/comment_form.php",
                    cache: false,
                    data: formData,
                    success: function (result) {
                        alert('Success');
                    },
                    error: function (request,error) {
                        alert('Network error has occurred please try again!');
                    }        

                });    

                return false;
            }); 
        });         
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>
                First Page
            </h3>
            <a href="#second" class="ui-btn-right">Next</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <form id="comment_form" data-ajax="false">
                    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value=""/>
                    <textarea id="text_area_input" name="comment" placeholder="Enter a comment here."></textarea>
                    <input type="submit" id="submit_comment" name="submit_comment" value="Post Comment"/>
             </form>
        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        </div>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I hit the submit button "loading" appears on the form page and nothing else happens. shouldn't it move to the submission page?

Comment: First why do you want it to more to submission page? What is the point of ajax if you want to move to destination php?

Comment: Ajax is here to prevent classic form submition. I have removed action and method form attributes because of this. Or have you have something else in mind?

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify. I do not want it to go to the submission page, but nothing happens when I click submit except the "loading" window appears on the screen.

Comment: Tell me have you copied my code? It should not move to the another page.

Comment: But I think I know what is a problem, can you try to use success and error callback like in my example?

Comment: I implemented your solution exactly with the success and errors callback. Is there anything I need to change on the submission page?

Comment: If it is not a problem for you mail me your page and I will take a look at it. You can find my mail inside my profile. Because i should work like in my example.

Comment: One more thing. I forgot. Can you add this attribute: data-ajax="false" inside a form element? It will prevent jQuery Mobile way of form handling. We want to do it on our own. Also can you add an alart warning inside a submit event, just to confirm event triggering.

Comment: I have found a problem. Not for my self, never test jQM form submition inside a jsFiddle example. I will my answer with a working html example.